# How to upload multiple image file in server?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I am trying to upload multiple image in server with using a asynctask httpclient. i know to how to upload single image but i cant know how to upload multiple image. i try like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < photo.length; i++) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo[photoIndex].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());
    params.put("uploaded_file[" + photo[i] + "]", in,
    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
}
```

Now I want to send file path how to send my file path in to PHP server.

In this code I am using bitmap Array photo[photoIndex] for multiple images. by this code I can capable to send bitmap of my multiple photo to the PHP server.

And this is code for upload single photo.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo[photoIndex].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());
params.put("uploaded_file", in,
System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
```

This is running properly.

Comment: Are you getting any Error to Upload multiple Images ?

Comment: no buddy ... but i can able to send multi bitmap on to server but i want o path of that file i dont know how to do that tell me that how can do that??

Comment: Instead of adding multiple image, why don't you create a zip file including images and then upload that zip and unzip that on server (by using php)

Comment: no bro i have to send file path coz i m working on live service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (String p : YOURARRAYLIST) {
       ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       photo[photoIndex].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
       InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());
       params.put("uploaded_file", in,
       System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
}
```